# Reinstall Windows XP over Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: windows, windows-xp, xubuntu

I recently installed Xubuntu 12.04 to my entire hard drive, overwriting Windows XP.
I tried to load my Recovery Disk in order to overwrite Xubuntu 12.04 and reinstall Windows XP.
The Recovery Disk went through all of the motions of writing files, etc. In the end after the computer ejected the disk and said it was ready to restart, it restarted into "grub rescue" error.

How do I reinstall with my Recovery Disk?

Answer (score 0):

looks like it is still recognizing the MBR of xubuntu even though the partitions has been removed You can try to format you hard disk using any DOS bootable disc to create windows compatible partition either **FAT 32 or NTFS** Then try to run recovery using the recovery disc.

Comment: DOS bootable disk?

Comment: it could be any formatting utility like partition wizard cd to create bootable disc and format the hdd you can try this freeware utility http://download.cnet.com/Partition-Wizard-Home-Edition/3000-2094_4-10962200.html?part=dl-6285158&subj=dl&tag=button